# How to expose Mailing Groups in webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, groups

I would like to create a webform with a certin mailing group exposed to the user via the checksum link, so that they can subscribe to the mailing group.

If I select "User Select" option during webform processing the entire list of groups of civicrm gets exposed. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this, please? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the form Element -> change live to static -> and select the groups you would like to put on the form.